# Count the number of variables assigned to a value in python

Tags: python, variables, global-variables, local-variables

How do I count the number of variables that are assigned in a script?

e.g. by line_no = 80 there are num_globals = y and num_locals = z.

**EDIT**

I understand that local variables do not all fall into one big collective local variables scope and they are in different local scopes but is there a good way to skim through a script and sum all of the local variables that we saw?

For example:

```
def foo():
    #Two local variables
    a=1
    b=2

def bar():
    #Two more local variables
    a=10
    for i in range(a):
        a+=1
    b=sum(i for i in range(10))

num_encountered_locals = 4
```

Comment: Do `len(locals())` and `len(globals())` accomplish what you're looking for?

Comment: I don't think so. I have just tried a simple test script: a=1, b=2, c=3 and I would have expected len(locals()) = 0 and len(globals()) = 3 but I got 11 and 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the following example from a fresh Python 3.4 command line boot:

```
>>> len(globals())
6
>>> len(locals())
6
```

Off the bat there are 6 global variables and because we're currently in the global scope, there are 6 local variables too:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> b = 2
>>> c = 3
>>> len(globals())
9
>>> len(locals())
9
```

Now we've added 3 variables, both of these are now 9.

```
>>> def foo():
...     a = 1
...     b = 2
...     print(len(locals()))
...     print(len(globals()))
...
```

Now we've added the function `foo` (this is defined in the global scope and so also is counted by globals/locals when at the global scope):

```
>>> print(len(locals()))
10
>>> print(len(globals()))
10
```

Lastly, note that within the function, only the variables within the function are in locals, while globals still contains everything in the global scope:

```
>>> foo()
2
10
```

Using this logic, you can use `len(locals())` to get the number of variables/functions defined within a function and `len(globals()) - 6` to get a list of all variables/functions defined in the global scope.

**Edit** *(Note that all of below is a fresh terminal)*

By using:

```
sum([not callable(globals()[i]) for i in globals()])
```

you can get the number of variables (excluding functions) currently in the global scope. By assigning this to a variable you can then get a list of currently defined variables:

```
>>> globs = sum([not callable(globals()[i]) for i in globals()])
>>> sum([not callable(globals()[i]) for i in globals()]) - globs - 1 # -1 for globs
0
```

Now:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> b = 2
>>> c = 3
>>> sum([not callable(globals()[i]) for i in globals()]) - globs - 1
3
>>> def foo():
...     a = 1
...     b = 1
...     print(len(locals()))
...
>>> foo()
2
>>> sum([not callable(globals()[i]) for i in globals()]) - globs - 1
3
```

Thus by adding `globs = sum([not callable(globals()[i]) for i in globals()])` at the top of your code, then every call hence forth of `sum([not callable(globals()[i]) for i in globals()]) - globs - 1` will give the defined number of variables at that point (this is at the global scope, you can use a similar method of `locs = sum([not callable(locals()[i]) for i in locals()])` to do the same inside a function).

**Edit 2**

I'm not sure there is a native way of doing what you've asked, however you've got a couple of options:

1. Parse the script (this is a lot of effort)
2. Keep a counter which you increment at the end of each function call:

```
>>> num_encountered_locals = 0
>>> def foo():
        global num_encountered_locals
        a = 1
        b = 2
        num_encountered_locals += len(locals())


>>> num_encountered_locals
0
>>> foo()
>>> num_encountered_locals
2
>>> foo()
>>> foo()
>>> foo()
>>> num_encountered_locals
8
```

(For some reason this last lot of code wouldn't format correctly so I had to put it in `<code>` and `<pre>` tags manually)

Comment: This is pretty much the test script I was using.

Comment: I was initially thinking about running a count from the global scope that would look through the previous lines, going through the functions line-by-line and tallying up local variables (just on the face of the script i.e. without getting caught up in iteration or recursion) to num_locals. I appreciate that num_locals probably isn't the right name for this.

Comment: @Astrophe im not sure I understand, can you update the question with an example test case and expected results

Comment: I have edited the question. I appreciate that it is unusual.

Comment: @Astrophe what about this?

Comment: Thanks, this is it.

Answer (score 1):

After execution of script, you can call `globals` and `locals`. These both return a dictionary . https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals

In order to count till line 80 ( for example) you need to stop the execution at that line(add a breakpoint maybe) and perhaps then call these methods.